# Ionic embed video - exit fullscreen mode

Tags: android, video, ionic-framework, embed

I have Ionic app with embedded Vimeo videos. I embed video as described in the official Vimeo [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding):

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/...?api=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Everything works well in browser.

In android emulator and real devices videos play in fullscreen mode. It's OK.

The problem happens when I try to exit fullscreen mode. On emulator and some devices when I press back button the app closes silently, on others - app closes with error.

What am I missing?

How can I exit the player and navigate back to the page where iframe with video is rendred?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Viktor I am facing same problem. Did you get any solution yet?

Comment: @Bilal Blu, I added own answer. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to play video using [cordova-plugin-streaming-media](https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media).
But you need a direct .mp4 link to the video file. It was my case because we had an Vimeo PRO account.

In controller:

```
var options = {
    orientation: "landscape"
};

$scope.playVideo = function() {
  window.plugins.streamingMedia.playVideo("http://.../video.mp4", options);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the plugin to latest version and make sure `<iframe />` tag should not be inside `<ion-item>` or any ionic tag. Just simply wrap `<iframe />` tag in `<div>` tag. It is working for me. Here is my code.

```
<div>
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/301857805?api=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&autopause=1"
    frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```